# Why won't the Take() work in this Linq to Sql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to take the first 10 records, but it is ignoring the `.take(10)` and returning all of the rows.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string getTopTenFeatured(int tab)
    {
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
        {

           IQueryable q = tab == 0? q = db.Items.Where(x => x.isFeatured == true)
               .OrderBy(x => x.title).Select(x=> x.title).Take(10): 
               q = db.Authors.Where(x=> x.isFeatured == true)
               .OrderBy(x => x.text).Select(x => x.text).Take(10);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("<ul>");
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var n in q)
            {
                i++;
                sb.AppendFormat("<li>{0}. {1}</li>", i, n);
            }
            sb.Append("</ul>");

            return sb.ToString();    
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** Nothing wrong here, `Projects` as opposed to `web sites` appparently have to be rebuilded manually. Hitting refresh in the browser does not do this automatically like a `web site` type project.

Comment: I just started using project instead of web site and apparently you have to build it to see the changes, using a web site type project you can just refresh the page :(

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the core LINQ expression - works in a quick sample I threw together.

Comment: I feel sorry for your QA department, if you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too many q='s in there.  Try this

```
   IQueryable q = (tab == 0) ?     

      db.Items
         .Where(x => x.isFeatured == true)    
         .OrderBy(x => x.title)
         .Select(x=> x.title).Take(10)  

   :  db.Authors.Where(x=> x.isFeatured == true)
          .OrderBy(x => x.text)
          .Select(x => x.text).Take(10);
```

Also, if you don't mind some constructive criticism, I don't think your web method should conflate these two return results.  Perhaps have a separate web method for each -- more strongly typed.  The checking of the tab should be done on the client side and the appropriate web method should be called.  Just a thought. :-)

Comment: I would prefer to do it this way so the front end code is as light as possible.